# Append image to HTML Area tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a click event to a html area on a map. If the area is clicked, a image should show up just in this area.

For example:

```
<area alt="" id="santiago" title="santiago" href="#" shape="poly" coords="225,692,281,695,277,744,225,743" />
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById("santiago").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      alert("CLICKED");
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/house.png');
    e.target.appendChild(img);
  });

};
```

The alert message is shown up if the area is clicked but the image won't show up. But it seems to be loaded because i can find the image in my code within the area tag. Can somebody help please? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried appending the created element rather than the path for display? `.appendChild(img);`

Comment: hi, yes that's what i've tried before - changed the sample now. thanks

Comment: What is the console.log(e.target) output?

Comment: The output is the example html area tag you can see above

Comment: If somebody is going to have this problem again, there seem to be problems appending an image to the html area tag in general. I've used div containers now and of course it works this way. thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<style>
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style> 
</style>    
</head>


<body>

<div class "container">
    <div class "picture">
        <img id="mapImage" src="put_text_heatmap.jpg"  height="1036px" width="1237px" usemap="#map">
        <map id="mapMap" name="map">
          <area data-brand="Ajile" href="dashboard_images/9.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="127, 629, 283, 869">
          <area data-brand="Honey" href="dashboard_images/8.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="514, 842, 803, 1024">
          <area data-brand="Akkriti" href="dashboard_images/7.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="774, 265, 909, 409">
          <area data-brand="Cosmatics" href="dashboard_images/6.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="985, 809, 1139, 992">
          <area data-brand="Annabelle" href="dashboard_images/5.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="258, 442, 429, 584">
          <area data-brand="Sunglases" href="dashboard_images/4.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="827, 851, 980, 1033">
          <area data-brand="VanHeusen" href="dashboard_images/3.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="343, 611, 514, 753">
          <area data-brand="jealous" href="dashboard_images/2.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="500, 358, 595, 409">
          <area data-brand="Denim" href="dashboard_images/1.PNG" id="snowballAppear" shape="rect" style="display: none" height="480px" width="640px" coords="163, 879, 334, 999">
        </map>
        
    </div>
</div>


</body>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("mapMap").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var img = document.createElement('img'); 
        $("#snowballAppear")[0].appendChild(img);
      });
};
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var img = document.createElement('img'); 
$("#santiago")[0].appendChild(img);
```